# Open a GDAL dataset with rasterio.open()

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, rasterio

I am processing geotiff files with GDAL and rasterio.
Every process of my processing chain generates a file in output.
What I want is saving every file in memory instead of creating files in the disk. I know how to do that with GDAL using the "MEM" argument. However, how can I use the produced file (here 'dataset') in rasterio as rasterio.open needs a filename. Is there a way to convert 'dataset' into a string or something like that?

My code:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
import rasterio
import numpy as np

# path
path = 'file.tif'

# open with GDAL
file = gdal.Open(path)
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadAsArray()
rotation = np.rot90(array)

# create memory file
x_pixels = array.shape[1]
y_pixels = array.shape[0]
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM")
dataset = driver.Create("", x_pixels, y_pixels, 1)
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)

# open the result with rasterio
with rasterio.open(dataset) as src:
    src_transform = src.transform
    src_crs = {'init': 'EPSG:3945'}
    dst_crs = {'init': 'EPSG:3945'}
    dst_transform, dst_width, dst_height = 
    calculate_default_transform(src_crs, dst_crs, x_pixels, y_pixels,                                                       
    gcps=gcps)

    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': dst_transform,
        'width': dst_width,
        'height': dst_height
    })
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-2770ecde2207>", line 65, in <module>
    with rasterio.open(dataset) as src:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rasterio\env.py", line 423, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 153, in open
    raise TypeError("invalid path or file: {0!r}".format(fp))
TypeError: invalid path or file: <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x00000131C7385A80> >
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to open the geotiff file trough Rasterio and create the Rasterio's MemoryFile using something like:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import numpy as np

# path
path = 'file.tif'

with rasterio.open(path) as src, MemoryFile() as memfile:
    array = src.read(1)
    rotation = np.rot90(array)
    x_pixels = array.shape[1]
    y_pixels = array.shape[0]
    profile = dict(src.profile)
    profile.update({'width': x_pixels, 'height': y_pixels})
    with memfile.open(**profile) as dataset:
        dataset.write(np.array([rotation]))
        # Remaining code
```

Comment: Thanks Joonala. However, every step of my processing chain (not shown here) finish by a georeferenced raster, which means I get everytime a GDAL dataset in ouput of the georeferencing (in memory). So I really need to process a GDAL dataset first instead of using rasterio for all the process.